# Deleted users still able to login

Tags: users

I have deleted all users in backend. However, they are still able to login and access the site. How can I permanently delete them?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using any custom plugin to manage users? In that case, you have to check the logic it uses to delete user.

Comment: Is this a multisite install or single install WP?

Answer (score 0):

It's an weird one. Go to the database and check users table to see if the deleted users are there or not. If they are there, delete the unwanted users except the admin.